# Problem sending two HTTP 1.1 requests to a server in the same socket

Tags: http, sockets, request

I'm trying to send two HTTP request to a server in the same socket, I got a response for the first request but nothing for the second,
I tried to send them using same or different buffer reader and BufferedWriter but always I have only response for request one and not both responses.

I'm too pressed by time please help me and thank you in advance,

```
 Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
 String strRequest1="myxmlRequest1....";
 //send request 
 wr.write("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
          wr.write("Host: HOST\r\n");
          wr.write("User-Agent: Java\r\n");
          wr.write("Content-Length: " + strRequest1.length() +  "\r\n");
          wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n");
          wr.write("Connection: Keep_alive\r\n\r\n");
          wr.write(strRequest1 +"\r\n");
          wr.flush();

// Get response
           rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                      socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));

          System.out.println( "BufferedReader rd------------------------------>" + rd);
          System.out.println( "readLine------------------------------>" + rd.toString());
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("output---------->" + output);
              output = output + line + "\n";
          }

          System.out.println("taille response" + output.length());
// Request 2
String s2="myxmlRequest2...";
//send request        
          BufferedWriter wr2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                   socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));

          System.out.println(s2);
          wr2.write("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
          wr2.write("Host: HOST\r\n");
          wr2.write("User-Agent: Java\r\n");
          wr2.write("Content-Length: " + s2.length() +  "\r\n");
          wr2.write("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n");
          wr2.write("Connection: Close\r\n\r\n");
          wr2.write(s2 + "\r\n");
          wr2.flush(); 

// get response 
          BufferedReader rd2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
          output="";
          while ((line = rd2.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("output2---------->" + output);
              output = output + line + "\n";
          }

          System.out.println("s2 response" + output.length()+"s2"+output);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      wr.write("Connection: Keep_alive\r\n\r\n");
                                ^---- should be a -
```

It's [`Keep-Alive`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01.html#Keep-Alive), with a dash, not an underscore.

Comment: And make sure to look at the server's actual response `Connection` header.  Just because a client requests `keep-alive` does not mean the server has to honor it.  If the server does not say `Connection: keep-alive` in its response, then assume the connection is being closed and make a new one.

Comment: I have replace it with Keep-Alive but the probleme is the same :( , my server response is Server: Apache
Pragma: AUTHORIZATION=administrator
Content-Length: 1193
Keep-Alive: timeout=120
Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: which mean that the server support Keep-Alive connection, then what is wrong why there is no response for tha second request? any idea would help me

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  I need to put the two request in same socket for a sepecific use.

Comment: Not particularly familiar with java, but can you re-use the `wr` object? You're creating two, and that might be seen as two separate requests, even though they're both using the same socket.

Comment: @sara: when reading a response, you are calling `BufferedReader.readln()` in a loop, which is fine for receiving just the HTTP response headers. But where are you reading the rest of the response data afterwards?  You need to look at the `Content-Length` and `Transfer-Encoding` response headers to know how to read the rest of the response data.  I don't see you doing that in the code you showed, so when the second response arrives, you still haven't finished reading the first response yet.